# Does android studio have any authentication function?

Tags: java, android, mysql, android-studio, authentication

i'm new to android studio, and i dont know much about it. My question here is do android provide any authentication method like aspx / php (laravel) that check if a user stay logged in and etc.

From what i learnt so far, i have to sign in to my app by receiving json/xml data from my web service, so my app just display the next screen after the id/password is correct? Is there any more security issue that i need to worried about? Aspx authentication do authenticate on every page even after your first login. But after some research i dont see android studio have this kind of authentication. Am i missing something?

Comment: You can manage login sessions by using [sharedpreferences](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/shared-preferences) or [sqlite](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase)

Comment: @AmrishKakadiya Sorry for the late reply, i had do some research on sharedpreferences, so i still need to check for authentication myself since it only stored some important data?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Firebase Authentication](https://firebase.google.com/products/auth?gclid=Cj0KCQjwqfz6BRD8ARIsAIXQCf3JzN-Uy6jWOgtJ_vJyow5AF7nzv9L0sVdubP1-UTkL7B38COY0XDAaAt-HEALw_wcB) for sign-in methods and user management.
You can add Firebase to Android Studio in Tools > Firebase.

Answer (score 0):

No there is no default function in android that does what you want, you have to add a new sdk to handle this issue. You Can Use Firebase as Aviad Nemet said. Or you save in the shared preferences that you user is authenticated after login success. Saving in the Shared Preferences is safe.